# Unmarshaling JSON with Apache Camel

Tags: json, rest, apache-camel

I use the Apache Camel component http4 to request data from a REST web service.

The response type of this REST service is JSON.

```
{"coord":{"lon":145.77,"lat":-16.92},"weather": 
[{"id":802,"main":"Clouds","description":"scattered 
clouds","icon":"03n"}],"base":"stations",
....
```

I have a JSON annotated Java Class which reflects the JSON structure

```
@JsonPropertyOrder({
    "coord",
    "weather",
    "base",
...

})
public class Report {

    @JsonProperty("coord")
    private Coord coord;
    @JsonProperty("weather")
    private List<Weather> weather = new ArrayList<Weather>();
    @JsonProperty("base")
    private String base;

...
```

Within the Camel Route I defined a JsonDataFormat which is referring to the annotated class.

```
...
public void configure() throws Exception {
    JsonDataFormat jsonDataFormat = new JsonDataFormat();
    jsonDataFormat.setUnmarshalType(Report.class);

    from(timer....).to("http4://${url}").unmarshal(jsonDataFormat).bean(myService);
```

this results in an Exception:

> com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException: coord    at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.DefaultMapper.realClass(DefaultMapper.java:81)
>   ~[xstream-1.4.9.jar:1.4.9]

- I tried to use the class Coord as unmarshalType
- I used the fully qualified name for the unmarshalType
- I also tried a pure Pojo without JSON-Annotations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try specifying Jackson as the JsonLibrary of your data format? The annotations you use are Jackson's yet XStream tries to perform the unmarshal:

```
JsonDataFormat jsonDataFormat = new JsonDataFormat(JsonLibrary.Jackson);
jsonDataFormat.setUnmarshalType(Report.class);
```

From everyhting I've seen this should work.

Comment: Yes, using JSONLibrary.Jackson was the solution, thank You